# Can't Render Google Directions Layer from HTML exported using Python embed_minimal_html

Tags: python, html, google-maps, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

After exporting a jupyter-gmaps base map and directions to HTML using "ipywidgets.embed.embed_minimal_html" I'm having trouble showing the directions layers when I re-open the HTML map.

The base map and directions layers show up just fine in jupyter notebook as shown here:
[Map and directions rendered in Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy1sU.png)

However, when the HTML file is re-opened using either a server (opened using "python -m http.server 8080"), or by double clicking on the saved file, or by using the code snippet below, only the base layer renders as shown here, along with some strange artifacts: [What is rendered when the exported HTML is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCOCT.png)

```
import IPython
IPython.display.HTML(filename='testest.html')
```

The directions layers seem to be saving in the HTML because I get an error regarding the directions layers when I try to save the image, but the scripts aren't being rendered in the browser ([Error about directions layer when opening the HTML file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTWyX.jpg).  Also, [the following errors are displayed Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L9oR.png).

Here is the code I used to generate this map, if someone could help me figure out how to get the directions layers to render in the exported map I would really appreciate it :) .

```
import gmaps
from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html,embed_data
import IPython
import os

#configure api
api_key = 'YOUR-API-KEY-HERE'
gmaps.configure(api_key=api_key)

#Define location 1, 2, and 3
Durango = (37.2753,-107.880067)
meow = (37.3654,-106.880067)
SF = (37.7749,-122.419416)

#Create the map
fig = gmaps.figure()

#create the layers
layer1 = gmaps.directions_layer(Durango, meow,travel_mode="DRIVING")
fig.add_layer(layer1)
layer2 = gmaps.directions_layer(Durango, SF,travel_mode="DRIVING")
fig.add_layer(layer2)

#Export the map and layers to HTML
embed_minimal_html(os.getcwd() + '\{}.html'.format("testest"), views=[fig],title='test')

#show the map in Jupyter
fig
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I've continued looking into this and have found that it may have something to do with the IPython kernel not being set up properly.  I'm still digging into it but will keep posting updates.

Comment: I am unfortunately still not able to solve this problem, if anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it.